# Sticking to OOP having a list containing objects of subtypes and filtering it by type

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

Is it a good practice to have a list containing objects of derived types and then filtering it by type checking when need to call methods specific for one of the types? From what I read typechecking is some kind of code smell and it indicates that OOP isn't fully used.

I use common list for object of all subtypes because I want to call some common methods on all objects. But some methods are specific for some subtype and if I want to invoke the method I need to filter out objects by type.

```
public abstract class ParentType
{
  public abstract void CommonMethod();
}

public class DerivedTypeA : ParentType
{
  public override void CommonMethod()
  {
    //do something
  }

  public void TypeASpecificMethod()
  {
    //do something
  }
}

public class DerivedTypeB : ParentType
{
  public override void CommonMethod()
  {
    //do something
  }

  public void TypeBSpecificMethod()
  {
    //do something
  }
}

static void Main()
{
  List<ParentType> objects = new List<ParentType>()
  {
    new DerivedTypeA(),
    new DerivedTypeA(),
    new DerivedTypeB(),
    new DerivedTypeB()
  }

  //Call common method on all objects in a list
  foreach(var obj in objects)
  {
    obj.CommonMethod();
  }

  //Call only specific method for DerivedTypeA objects
  foreach(var obj in objects)
  {
    if(obj is DerivedTypeA derivedAObj) //type checking needed
    {
      derivedAObj.TypeASpecificMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: C# 8.0's pattern matching exists just for this kind of thing.

Comment: This should not be problem tbh. There is also a method called ``typeof()`` to get the type at compilation time. If you want to get the type at execution time then you gotta use the method ``GetType()``

Comment: I'm using pattern matching in this example but the problem is not a technique of getting type here.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, this is not OOP. The OOP solution would be to have each type's implementation of `CommonMethod` call other specific methods as appropriate for the type.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the following code:

```
foreach (var obj in objects)
{
    if (obj is DerivedTypeA) 
    {
        obj.TypeASpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

As your logic evolves, you are likely to end up with something like this:

```
foreach (var obj in objects)
{
    if (obj is DerivedTypeA) 
    {
        obj.TypeASpecificMethod();
    }
    else if (obj is DerivedTypeB)
    {
        obj.TypeBSpecificMethod();
    }
    else if (obj is DerivedTypeC)
    {
        obj.TypeCSpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

The above code violates the [Open-closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) principle:

> code should be open for extension, but closed for modification

Since this is a hypothetical question, it's difficult to give you a solution...

In a real world scenario, you could look into **Inversion of Control**. Dependency Injection and Factory Pattern are popular forms of IoC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the code you provide violates SOLID principles, you should avoid  if statement for checking if type is right. You can use Strategy pattern and Factory that creates different strategies at run time.

Comment: I understand why my example violates open-closed principle but could you give me an example how to use strategy and factory pattern in a case where I want to have a common collection for all subtypes and sometimes invoke common methods and sometimes specific one?

Comment: For this case I would suggest to have not one collection but split them in 2 or 3 one for common method execution and one for specific and make a interface segregation. To give you more concrete example I need to know more details about the case and problem what you want to solve. I don't really understand why you need a collection of all classes. You can contact me and we can discuss in details! I think you problem can be refactored and solved in totally other way!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no problem, on the contrary, you do things correctly using OOP.

First you use polymorphism in one its primary purpose to parse a list of objects of differents types having the same base type and you call the same method.

Then you use type matching to apply a special case to a non-specific list of objects of differents types having the same base type to act only on those that is a specific child type.

These are two elementary case studies.

You transgress nothing.

For example, in the real world, a car washer:

- Will wash the outside of different types of cars in the same way: it will pass the cars one after the other and apply the same method on each, it's your first loop - he has nothing to do with the type of cars since they are cars.
- Then, let's say that its purpose is to affix a label only on cars that have two doors and not four, this is your second loop - he takes care of the type of the car to apply something only on a specific gender.

OOP exists to represent the reality and use this representation in the most natural, simple, effective and robust way possible... so stay smart.

Hence you may write this:

```
objects.OfType<DerivedTypeA>().ToList().ForEach(o => o.TypeASpecificMethod());
```

And you will be sturdy.